# Jupyter notebooks - convert to html - no images?

Tags: python, html, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm converting a Jupyter notebook to html (using the dropdown list in the browser), and everything else looks fine but my images aren't showing. I've included them in markdown cells as, e.g.

```
<img src="create_random_dist.png" style="width: 500px;" align="left">
```

Why doesn't this work? Please help!

I did a search but the solutions that worked for other people don't seem to work for me...

Comment: Doesn't work as in you are getting errors in the console/network tab or doesn't work as in you see the markup or doesn't work as in you don't even see the element when you inspect the dom? Also where are you trying to view the page? If you just don't know start with looking at the network tab and see if the browser can find the file and go from there.

Comment: Doesn't work as in it comes up with alternative text or a blank space. I can see the figures fine in the actual notebook, but not when I convert to html (or PDF, even) and view it in my browser (latest firefox).

Comment: Check the network tab in FF and ensure the path is correct to your resource. If the image isn't sitting in the same folder as the html file it won't display, and of course you probably already have done so, but double check the spelling is exactly the same and that it is indeed a png

Comment: Haha I see. I was being stupid and viewing it from my downloads folder, rather than where the images are stored. Thanks!!

Comment: @scrappedcola Can you post your comment as an answer? Thanks!